# Automated Cleanup of Long StringBuilder?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, resharper, stringbuilder

I am creating a large SQL statement using the `StringBuilder.Append()` method in VB.NET.  I would like to just put the whole SQL statement in one `Append()` block and use some sort of feature to automatically create many `Append()` blocks to clean up the code.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and ReSharper 7, but I can't find anyway to do this except for manually adding `Append()` blocks.  ReSharper's code cleanup surprisingly didn't help.

Is this possible?

EDIT for further clarification:

I would like to be able to write one long Append() and have the IDE or some plugin separate it into several Appends() for aesthetic purposes.

For example:

```
Dim sql As New StringBuilder

sql.Append("SELECT Condition1 AS ""THIS_NAME"", Condition2 AS ""THIS_OTHER_NAME"", Condition3 AS ""ANOTHER_NAME"", Condition4 AS ""ANOTHER_NAME"", Condition5 AS ""THIS_NAME"" FROM MY_TABLE WHERE Condition1 = 'ThisValue' AND Condition2 = 'ThisOtherValue' AND Condition3 = 'ThisOtherValue' AND Condition4 = 'AnotherValue' AND Condition5 = 'SomeOtherValue'")
```

The above Append() is lengthy and not very readable.  However, it is sometimes difficult to get ALL the syntax correct when splitting up SQL statements into several Append blocks.  I'd like some plugin to transform it to the following:

```
sql.Append("SELECT Condition1 AS ""THIS_NAME"",")
sql.Append(" Condition2 AS ""THIS_OTHER_NAME"",")
sql.Append(" Condition3 AS ""ANOTHER_NAME"",")
sql.Append(" Condition4 AS ""ANOTHER_NAME"",")
sql.Append(" Condition5 AS ""THIS_NAME"",")
sql.Append(" FROM MY_TABLE"",")
sql.Append(" WHERE Condition1 = 'ThisValue'")
```

....And so on.. It doesn't have to be formatted exactly in that manner, just a separation that splits it into several Append statements.

Comment: It really is not at all clear what you are asking for here.  Perhaps you could show us an example from your code?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I edited this question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is: "No, there's no R# ability for this."

However if this is purely for formatting, a much more appropriate solution is to have your [String literals be spread across multiple lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5chcthbw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

You don't want to pollute your code with a dozen method calls to achieve the same thing.

```
    sql.Append("SELECT Condition1 as ""THIS_NAME""," & _
               " Condition2 as ""THIS_OTHER_NAME""," & _
               " Condition3 AS ""ANOTHER_NAME"",")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not understanding your issue fully I think, but here you can add any amount of SQL statement...

```
  Dim SQLBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder

   SQLBuilder.Append("YOUR SQL STATEMENT")
```

Now I am not sure what you mean by adding many append blocks to clean-up code? Could you possibly explain in greater detail so we can help you?

I was going to say if you want to clear the StringBuilder you can just emtpy this before filling it again....

```
 SQLBuilder.Remove(0, SQLBuilder.Length)
```

If all you are doing is creating a statement, why not just declare a string variable to hold this statement? See below...

```
 Dim strSQLQuery As String = "YOUR STATEMENT"
```

Then you can use this where you want to and set it anytime...

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `SqlBuilder.Remove(0, SqlBuilder.Length)` you can use `SqlBuilder.Length = 0`, or in .NET 4.0 and later, `SqlBuilder.Clear()`.